# Multithreading File hashing in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

working on a project to increase the performance of a program that hashes the content of a file to standard hashes(md5, sha...)

I was trying to incorporate multithreading in order to do so but struggle to code this. Any tips or recommended readings will be very appreciated! My code looks like the following

EDIT: So the question is how can I use multithreading within this code to speed it up, by for example splitting parts of the file up and assigning them to different cores.

;

```
 #include <fstream>
   using namespace std;
   #include "md5.h"
   #include "sha256.h"
   #include "sha3.h"
   #include <iostream>
int main(int, char**)
{
    cout << "   HASHING ALGORITHMS:" << endl;
    cout << "................................................." << endl << endl;

    MD5 md5;
    SHA256 sha256;
    SHA3 sha3;
    std::string hash1 = md5("enwik8");
    std::cout << "Hash of File: " << md5(hash1) << endl << endl;

    //Next part is to hash the actual content of file. 
    /*
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("data.txt.txt");

    char output[100];

    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {

        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {

            /*
            myReadFile >> output;
            cout << "Input: " << output << endl << endl;
            sha3(output);
                cout <<"SHA256: ";
                std::cout << sha256(output) << std::endl;
                cout << "SHA3:   ";
            std::cout << sha3(output) << endl << endl; 
        }
        myReadFile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed loading file.";
    }

    */


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that it is the processing and not the file io that makes your code run slow? Btw you forgot to ask a question. In case this is working code and you want a review you should move this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @user463035818 Yea it is the file io that makes the code slow but was hoping to learn some more about multithreading at the moment and how to use that in this code. Oh right sorry will do that. thanks :)

Comment: *So the question is how can I use multithreading within this code to speed it up, by for example splitting parts of the file up and assigning them to different cores.* How do you first plan on splitting the file and assigning the parts to different **disks**?  If disk IO is your bottleneck, hammering one disk with more threads will actually slow down your IO performance.

Comment: Take a look at boost::coroutine.... there are a lot of tutorials/examples
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html

Comment: I second Andrew, the code you have there is probably not the best example to use multithreading. Be warned that more threads does by no means always result in more speed

Comment: Ah right okay. Are there any recommended programs in which I could use multithreading, like a password cracker for example @user463035818 thanks for the reply btw :)

Answer (score 1):

There are few useful hash functions which are not inherently sequential, thus multiple processors will not help.

If your program intends to compute multiple hashes of each file ( it isn’t obvious from your program fragment ), each hash could be computed in parallel.   In that case, your primary job is buffer management, which could be a simple as mapping the entire file into memory, then dispatching a thread for each hash function.

If you are looking for practise with parallel programming, problems which can be partitioned are your friend.  Sorting is a good example: you have N items and M processors; so you can shrink O(Nlg(N)) to O((1+N/M)lg(N/M))